# curl POST login

Tags: curl, zabbix, fba

We have SharePoint Forms Based Authentication. I would like to use Curl and get site content using this authentication.  Using FireFox Tamper Data I got this POSTDATA information:

```
POSTDATA=__VIEWSTATE=%dlkgKDFLFKF54FFEF564FEVv5ve56rv4e6rv546E5vre%4F
&
__EVENTVALIDATION=%fwf5we4fEEFefe544654fe54F5eF
&
Login_UserInput=username
&
Login_PasswordInput=passw
&
LoginButton=Login
```

Login page url: https://subdomain.domain.local/_layouts/Company/Login/FormsLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F

URL after logn: https://subdomain.domain.local/companysites/siteCollection/subsite/Pages/LandingPage.aspx

Command I used to get web content with curl:

```
curl.exe -F "POSTDATA=__VIEWSTATE=%dlkgKDFLFKF54FFEF564FEVv5ve56rv4e6rv546E5vre%4F&__EVENTVALIDATION=%fwf5we4fEEFefe544654fe54F5eF&Login_UserInput=username&Login_PasswordInput=passw&ButtonLogin=Login" https://subdomain.domain.local/sites/siteCollection/subsite/Pages/LandingPage.aspx -k
```

But always getting: 403 FORBIDDEN

What could be wrong?

Comment: `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` are your problems. Those are unique tokens, and can change on every request. You'll need to grab fresh ones from the login page each time.

Comment: Jeremiah, how to grab fresh ones from the login page each time?

Comment: You'd have to request the login form, parse the html and retrieve the values. Most scripting language include ways to do this, if you're familiar with one.

Answer (score 0):

The `-F` option produces a multipart/form-data request but your website may just require a regular POST with `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So try with:

```
curl.exe -k -d "POSTDATA=__VIEWSTATE=%dlkgKDFLFKF54FFEF564FEVv5ve56rv4e6rv546E5vre%4F&__EVENTVALIDATION=%fwf5we4fEEFefe544654fe54F5eF&Login_UserInput=username&Login_PasswordInput=passw&ButtonLogin=Login" https://subdomain.domain.local/sites/siteCollection/subsite/Pages/LandingPage.aspx
```